# Not able to fetch roles from Db in Many-to-Many association using Spring Security, Jpa and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I'm trying to develop a small app using Spring Boot + spring security as a backend, (with Jpa and Hibernate on the persistence side of things) and Angular as a frontend. I'm in the login/register user phase, and all is good on the frontend side of things; the correct data is reaching the backend. It's just that when trying to get through security things aren't working because i can't fetch the roles from the db correctly. i'm a bit new to spring security, so please bear with me. I'm using a many-to-many association in my User and Role class:

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private boolean enabled;
    // bi-directional many-to-many association to Role
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Role role: this.getRoles()) {
            SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName());
        }
        return authorities;
    }

//constructors

//getters and setters
```

My Role class:

```
@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String USER = "USER";
    public static final String ROLE_USER = "ROLE_USER";
    public static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";
    public static final String ROLE_MODERATOR = "ROLE_MODERATOR";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    // bi-directional many-to-many association to User
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

//constructors

//getters and setters
```

My UserRepo:

```
public interface UserRepositorio extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN FETCH u.roles WHERE u.email = :email")
    public User getUserByEmail(@Param("email") String email);

}
```

As you can see, i'm trying to use the FETCH directive as per other sources, as the best way to deal with many to many relationships; by not using the fetch = FetchType.EAGER directly in the Many-to-Many annotation, to avoid future performance issues.

BUT, i have tried with the Fetchtype.Eager. I have used Sets, i have used Lists. Nothing works.

I can create the users and the roles just fine - a user_role table is generated in my database, and the enteties are persisted correctly.

I am creating the User in my main app, implementing the commandLineRunner interface, just to test things out:

```
@Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        Role roleUser = new Role(Role.ROLE_USER);
        Role roleAdmin = new Role(Role.ROLE_ADMIN);
        roles.add(roleUser);
        roles.add(roleAdmin);
        userService.saveUser(new User("user1", passwordEncoder.encode("1234"), "miguel@gmail.com", roles, true));
    }
```

Here's the console output when i try to fetch the data:

```
2021-06-07 09:29:26.121 DEBUG 12672 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select user0_.id as id1_1_0_, role2_.id as id1_0_1_, user0_.email as email2_1_0_, user0_.enabled as enabled3_1_0_, user0_.password as password4_1_0_, user0_.username as username5_1_0_, role2_.name as name2_0_1_, roles1_.user_id as user_id1_2_0__, roles1_.role_id as role_id2_2_0__ from user user0_ inner join user_role roles1_ on user0_.id=roles1_.user_id inner join role role2_ on roles1_.role_id=role2_.id where user0_.email=?

2021-06-07 09:29:26.124 TRACE 12672 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [miguel@gmail.com]
2021-06-07 09:29:26.127 TRACE 12672 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_1_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [1]
2021-06-07 09:29:26.127 TRACE 12672 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_0_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [1]
2021-06-07 09:29:26.130 TRACE 12672 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([email2_1_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [miguel@gmail.com]
2021-06-07 09:29:26.132 TRACE 12672 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([enabled3_1_0_] : [BOOLEAN]) - [true]
2021-06-07 09:29:26.132 TRACE 12672 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([password4_1_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [$2a$10$RzPzVJMpfz8qMd0xspx3U.9aDyWRWvYw7tbcL8z/03MbFDmNyq99K]
2021-06-07 09:29:26.132 TRACE 12672 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([username5_1_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [user1]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what exactly is your issue here?
The query in the console seems correct and the fetched values seems correct too

Comment: My issue is that i can't retrieve the user roles from the database, which is what i'm trying to do, along with retrieving the user data. If i don't user the JOIN FETCH directive in my query, whilst debugging, i'll actually get a lazy load exception; but when i do, nothing whatsoever gets back, despite the values being shown in the console - i have actually some souts in my userServiceImpl, in my loadByUserName method, but they stop printing information when the code gets to "User user = userRepositorio.getUserByEmail(email);", which seems weird to me.

Comment: You need to set the roles field of User yourself before saving and users field of Role as well before saving. Are you doing that. I suspect that is the issue?
After saving did you check the DB if everything is saved correctly?

Comment: Yup, indeed it is being saved correctly in the Db. As you can see above, when i'm saving the user in the db, i am settings his roles through the constructor; i wasn't setting the user in the roles though... I did now, but still it doesn't work :/

Comment: Just a suggestion: you might want to simplify your model. Do you have a need for the getUser->getRoles->getAllUserForRole relationship (i.e. fetch all users for the role of user x?). If not, just store the role as an list in a single colum, and check on isPresent. Create a seperate lookup for findByRole if needed. Your approach might be a bit overkill. 

Also you could extend your repository with CrudRepository and just use List<User> findByEmail(String email); 
Adding an index in your db on the email column will help you with performance. Make the role an enum and you optimize further.